# Mass inappropriate tag-removal edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

A [particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3413108/andi) is suggesting hundreds of edits, most of which do nothing but remove the [windows] tag from questions that are also tagged [python].

It seems to me, based on the "If your question has nothing to do with ... Windows-specific behaviour then do not use this tag", questions that *are* Windows-specific may legitimately use the [windows] tag.

Assuming the above is true, I think all of the following did deserve the [windows] tag:

- [Python under windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186892/python-under-windows)
- [why os.environ['path'] is different from what I have in advanced>environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574342/why-os-environpath-is-different-from-what-i-have-in-advancedenvironment-var)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762906/controlling-windows-applications-sound-using-python
- [Uninstall software from your computer using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457546/uninstall-software-from-your-computer-using-python)
- [Python scripts stopped running on double-click in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521456/python-scripts-stopped-running-on-double-click-in-windows)
- [DLL load failed with scipy.optimize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753695/dll-load-failed-with-scipy-optimize)
- [Python copy larger file too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799210/python-copy-larger-file-too-slow)
- [How can I convert my pygame game to an .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482770/how-can-i-convert-my-pygame-game-to-an-exe)
- [vim-ipython failed on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205281/vim-ipython-failed-on-windows-7)
- [Running remote windows GUI application through ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524619/running-remote-windows-gui-application-through-ssh)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116665/create-another-windows-7-user-with-all-the-python-configuration
- [Screenshot of external window in windows in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170687/screenshot-of-external-window-in-windows-in-python)
- [How to launch python script as a windows Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308329/how-to-launch-python-script-as-a-windows-services)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106678/windows-registry-mru

In addition, the user is spamming the review queue by mostly just making tag-removal edits and not fixing the other issues in the questions. The questions above all still contain spelling/capitalization/formatting/etc. issues that could have been addressed in the suggested edits, but were not.

I also noticed a handful of questions where the relevant [windows] tag was removed, but the inapplicable [python] tag was not removed:

- [How to open Windows Explorer via link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598232/how-to-open-windows-explorer-via-link)
- ["load data infile" with many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491102/load-data-infile-with-many-files)
- [Linux identifies identical .py files as different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437228/linux-identifies-identical-py-files-as-different)

Comment: What really doesn't make sense is that reviewers would actually approve the removal a tag that is even **directly in the name of the question itself** and appears to be important to the question.  Maybe they have an auto-clicker for the approve button?

Comment: Indeed. Sometimes it doesn't belong in the title (when it's not actually relevant), but in those cases the suggested edit should be removing it from the title too.

Comment: I can't remember, but have we had a discussion recently about throttling per-day or per-hour edits by individual users, or having a per-day cap on reputation earned via edits?

Comment: Not all that much that can be done here, until/unless the review system gets a major overhaul.  You can flag the posts in the hope that a moderator will review ban some of these bad reviewers and perhaps give the editor a talking to.  And of course you can roll back the inappropriate edits, if you're confident that the edit is in error.

Comment: @BradLarson I don't remember it recently, I do remember having it a while ago.  I don't remember any major drawbacks or objections to the idea.

Comment: @Servy - Yeah, without us having [some way to ban editors](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits), I'm thinking of the best way to combat this. The problem is largely the rate at which this is done. A few minor tag edits might be fine, but a rapid-fire bunch is a problem. Are there any reasonable use cases for supporting dozens of suggested edits in a single hour?

Comment: @BradLarson In theory, yes.  People are certainly physically capable of spending an hour making several dozen good edits.  In practice, I don't really see it happening.  Most good editors I come across are the people that just edit the posts that they come across naturally in the process of trying to answer questions.  Granted, that's not an objective metric.

Comment: @Servy: If someone is active on meta and agrees with a [meta-tag:burninate-request], he might do the whole work for 10-20 questions in a row. Anyway, it seems anything more than doing the retag and quoting the meta-post as an excuse to only doing the easy part is beyond many...

Comment: Too minor, right?

Comment: Sounds like a friend of http://stackoverflow.com/users/3611023/brainy?tab=reputation&sort=time (who has been dealt with yesterday in another meta post I can't find right now)

Comment: @Anonymous: Search for "robo aprove" in recent meta questions and you will find this being a real issue these days.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yea, I've seen quite a few questions about this on meta and robo-reviewers in the review queue.  Still, it just seems ridiculous.

Comment: @Anonymous: It is the second side of the medal for gamification of this site. Remember when scripts turned up for mining unicoins? Approving every edit is an easy way to some badges.

Comment: @Deduplicator In my experiences, the people doing tag cleanup work correctly are virtually always 2k+ rep users.  I've yet to see a tag cleanup effort really done well by anyone just suggesting edits.  Actively removing non-2k users from having the ability to participate in tag cleanups seems not only acceptable to me, but almost certainly advantageous.

Comment: @Servy I saw a <2k user doing valid tag cleanup on SO sometime in the last week.  He appeared to was working through a tag for a relatively uncommon tool/platform that was vulnerable to misuse as a meta-tag.  The half dozen or so edits of his I reviewed were all good.

Comment: @DanNeely And I've seen more than half a dozen <2k users *improperly* performing tag changes in just this past week.  I'm sure that somewhere out there there's at least 1 user appropriately suggesting tag cleanup edits, but the vast majority of them are not.

Comment: So what about removing the [tag:microsoft] tags? Is that acceptable?